# How I get the field smallAttributeValue from table ddmfieldattribute in Liferay 7.4?

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

Liferay 7.4 stores the structure data in the "ddmfieldattribute" table. I'm trying to get the fields of the structures in the ADT template, but I can't find the solution.

**The structure has the following fields:**

- title
- content

**The ADT code is as follows:**

```
<#assign dlService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.document.library.kernel.service.DLFileEntryLocalService")>

<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as entry>
        <#if entry.getClassName() == "com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle" >      
            //Get the fields from the structure
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working fine. I have managed to get the data from the "title" and "content" fields of the structure in an ADT template. (Liferay 7.4)

```
<#assign dlService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.document.library.kernel.service.DLFileEntryLocalService")>
<#assign ddmFieldLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.service.DDMFieldLocalService")/>

<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as entry>
        <#if entry.getClassName() == "com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle" >      
            <#assign assetRenderer = entry.getAssetRenderer()/>
            <#assign journalArticle = assetRenderer.getAssetObject() />
            <#assign ddmStructure = journalArticle.getDDMStructure() />
            <#assign ddmForm = ddmStructure.getDDMForm()/>
            <#assign ddmFormValues = ddmFieldLocalService.getDDMFormValues(ddmForm, journalArticle.getId()) />
            <#assign ddmFormFieldValues = ddmFormValues.getDDMFormFieldValues() />

            <#list ddmFormFieldValues as fieldName>
                <#if fieldName.getFieldReference() == 'titulo'>
                    ${fieldName.getValue().getString(locale)}
                </#if>

                <#if fieldName.getFieldReference() == 'contenido'>
                    ${fieldName.getValue().getString(locale)}
                </#if>
            </#list>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood what you want, but you can get the Entry's Journal Article (same as Web Content) from inside a Widget Template freemarker with:

```freemarker
assetRenderer = entry.getAssetRenderer()
journalArticle = assetRenderer.getArticle()
```

and then get its structure:

```freemarker
articleDDMStructure = journalArticle.getDDMStructure()
```

and its fields:

```freemarker
ddmFormFields = getDDMFormFields(false)
```

P.S.: [this](https://github.com/jordanamorais/lfrgs-frontend-samples/tree/master/adts/examples) github repository contains some great ADT examples

Comment: Thanks for the help, your code helped me solve the problem. Regards

Comment: I'm happy to help! If my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it. Regards

Comment: I have given your comment a point because it helped me to solve the problem. However, I have put the solution in the comment below. Thanks.